# How many times can I use The Shiny Orb?

Tags: small-world-underground

Say I'm playing a Vampiric Race and have The Shiny Orb. Another player has a ton of territories with only single units in them adjacent to me. Can I use vampire to take one and then The Shiny Orb to take another?

What about if I am a Magic race and have The Shiny Orb? Can I effectively use it twice on each opponent? Twice total on two different opponents?

My confusion arises because in the "shorthand rules" for The Shiny Orb it specifies once per turn per opponent, but in the rule book it says once per opponent. It also says that it counts the same as Vampirism in the full rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rulebook (page 14) states that the Shiny Orb can only be used once per turn.  Nothing about per opponent.  You can use it but once each turn.

You can use it in addition to the Vampire power (which can be used once per opponent per turn.

If you are Magic, then you can use it one additional time, on the same or different opponent.